# Extracting runtime maven information

Tags: java, maven, runtime, maven-plugin

I would like to write a plugin that will extract maven's runtime information such as execution "Total Time", The maven command line used by the user, etc...

Anyone has an idea how to do that?

Thanks,
Shay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at how to write your own [Maven Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).

That guide is not using Java Annotations but that is also possible: [Using Plugin Tools Java5 Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html).

You can access the project definitions from inside your Mojo (A mojo is a Maven plain Old Java Object).

Comment: Thanks to your hint I was able to do it. I injected MavenSession that contains all of that information. 10x!